# how to block ftp connection with ufw or iptables

Tags: networking, iptables, ftp

I wanted to do a very basic thing - block and then enable a ftp connection between my two virtualbox ubuntus (18.04) and I cannot do that. This is what I understand about it and did:
I have sv1 and sv2, I want to block ftp from sv2 to sv1

1. I installed vsftpd on sv1 ( apt-get install vsftpd )
2. Now I can ftp from sv2 to sv1
3. Now I would like to block this connection, I set ufw status to disable all from sv2 and I also added a IPTABLES rule.

I would very much appreciate an explanation of what is happening here :(

```
root@pawel-VirtualBox:/home/pawel# ufw status  Status: active
 To                         Action      From
 Anywhere                   DENY     192.168.56.101
```

I added IPTables rule:

```
iptables -L -n | grep 21
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
```

I still can ftp from sv2 to sv1

```
root@pawel-VirtualBox:/home/pawel# ftp 192.168.56.101 21 
Connected to 192.168.56.101.
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
Name (192.168.56.101:pawel): pawel
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Comment: There's more than one FTP port - one's a control port and one's normal.  But you have two ACCEPT rules first that override your DENY rule

Comment: ok thank you and sorry for such basic question!
I managed to do what I want by adding an iptables rule of highest precedence (on the top)

Comment: for anybody who would like to do same thing one can do this :
iptables -I  INPUT 1 -p TCP --dport 21 -j ACCEPT <- adding rule of highest precedence  that accepts conn on port 21
iptables -D INPUT 1   <- deleting rule of highest precedence 
iptables -I  INPUT 1 -p TCP --dport 21 -j DROP <- adding rule of highest precedence that blocks port 21
it's more elegant to replace rules rather than dropping and recreating new ones but this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ufw deny ftp` assuming you have standard ports should achieve what you requested without falling back to iptables

`sudo ufw allow ftp` to reverse or have I misunderstood?